# How to manage Long Paths in Bash?

Tags: bash, path

I have a problem to manage long paths. How can I get quickly to paths like

```
/Users/User/.../.../.../.../.../Dev/C/card.c
```

I tried an alias

```
alias cd C='cd /Users/User/.../.../.../.../.../Dev/C'
```

but I am unable to do aliases for two separate words. I have long lists of Bash aliases and paths in CDPATH, so I am hesitating to make them more. How can manage long paths?

**[Ideas for Replies]**

The user litb's reply revealed some of my problems in the management. Things, such as "CTRL+R", "!-3:1:2:4:x" and "incremental search", are hard for me. They probably help in navigating long directories and, in the sense, management.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Consider using symbolic links. I have a `~/work/` directory where I place symlinks to all my current projects.

You may also use shell variables:

```
c='/Users/User/.../.../.../.../.../Dev/C'
```

Then:

```
cd "$c"
```

Comment: I faced a problem when I changed directories. I solved it with shell variables and symlinks:

Dev='/Users/User/Dev/'
site='$Dev/.../C/.../site'

They are very powerful combination :)

Comment: Don't forget that you should "quote" your parameter expansions.

    cd "$c"

It also makes it a bit more cumbersome again; but you **should** stick to this practice.  So yeah, symlinks are probably the best way.

Comment: @lhunanth Sorry I cannot see no difference between:
cd $c
and
cd "$c"
Is it about protecting kernel from me or something?

Comment: @UnixBasics: If the directory contain spaces, $c will become two or more arguments, that is probably not what you want. If $c doesn't contain spaces, it is fine to just cd $c.

Comment: @UnixBasics: Moreover, quotes also protect against pathname expansion.  The following will also break for a different reason entirely: foo="/Pictures/ * Mom"; cd $foo (If you put bullet points in your picture tag dirnames: * will expand to all directories in your **current** path!)

Answer (score 38):

Using *symlinks* is probably the best idea; but you can do it even easier than dumping them all into your home directory.

As you mentioned, BASH has a feature called **CDPATH** which comes in really handy here.

Just make a hidden folder in your homedir (so it doesn't clutter your homedir too much):

```
$ mkdir ~/.paths
$ cd ~/.paths
$ ln -s /my/very/long/path/name/to/my/project project
$ ln -s /some/other/very/long/path/to/my/backups backups
$ echo 'CDPATH=~/.paths' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

This creates a directory in your homedir called ".paths" which contains symlinks to all your long directory locations which you regularly use, then sets the CDPATH bash variable to that directory (in your .bashrc) and re-reads the .bashrc file.

Now, you can go to any of those paths from *anywhere*:

```
$ cd project
$ cd backups
```

Leaving you with a short CDPATH, no cluttering aliasses, and more importantly:  A really easy way to navigate to those long paths from **other applications**, such as UI applications, by just going into ~/.paths or adding that directory into your UI application's sidebar or so.

Probably the easiest all-round solution you can have.

Answer (score 6):

Create symlinks in your home directory (or somewhere else of your choosing)

`ln -s` *longDirectoryPath  ~/MySymLinkName*

See `man ln` for more details.

Comment: Sorry, it took me three days to understand your reply. For future readers, the signs > and < are not about redirecting stdout or anything like that. If I correctly understood, Dan meant:

$ ln -s long_directory_path ~/MySoftLinkName

Comment: Sorry about that brain fault. I'll edit the text to use italics instead of <...>

Comment: I just learned that symbolic links are also called "softlinks" :-)

Comment: My age is showing there :-) I first encountered (sym|soft)links on Apollo Domain systems, at a time when they hadn't come to Unix yet (at least, not to standard-ish Unix implementations.) On those systems, they were called "softlinks". I've changed the answer to use "symlinks" instead.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the easiest solution is to use:

```
alias cdc='cd /Users/User/.../.../.../.../.../Dev/C'
alias cdbin='cd /Users/User/.../.../.../.../.../Dev/bin'
alias cdtst='cd /Users/User/.../.../.../.../.../Dev/tst'
```

if you're only really working on one project at a time. If you work on multiple projects, you could have another alias which changed the directories within those aliases above.

So, you'd use something like:

```
proj game17
cdc
make
proj roman_numerals
cdbin
rm -f *
proj game17 ; cdc
```

Since this is a useful thing to have, I decided to put together a series of scripts that can be used. They're all based aroung a configuration file that you place in your home directory, along with aliases to source scripts. The file `"~/.cdx_data"` is of the form:

```
scrabble:top=~/dev/scrabble
scrabble:src=~/dev/scrabble/src
scrabble:bin=~/dev/scrabble/bin

sudoku:top=~/dev/scrabble
sudoku:src=~/dev/scrabble/src
sudoku:bin=~/dev/scrabble/bin
sudoku:data=~/dev/scrabble/data
```

and lists all the relevant projects (scrabble and sodoku in this case) and their directories (which may be different for each project, but have top, bin, src and data in this example).

The first action is to initialize stuff, so put:

```
. ~/.cdx_init
```

at the end of your .bash_profile and create the `"~/.cdx_init"` file as:

```
alias cdxl='. ~/.cdx_list'
alias projl='. ~/.cdx_projlist'
alias cdx='. ~/.cdx_goto'
alias proj='. ~/.cdx_proj'
```

This sets up the four aliases to source the files which I'll include below. Usage is:

```
cdxl     - List all directories in current project.

projl    - List all projects.

proj     - Show current project.
proj <p> - Set current project to <p> (if allowed).

cdx      - Show current project/directory and expected/actual real
           directory, since they can get out of sync if you mix cd and cdx.
cdx .    - Set actual real directory to expected directory (in other words,
           get them back into sync).
cdx <d>  - Set directory to <d> (if allowed).
```

The actual script follow. First, `".cdx_list"` which just lists the allowed directories in the current project (pipelines are broken into multiple lines for readability but they should all be on one line).

```
echo "Possible directories are:"
cat ~/.cdx_data
    | grep "^${CDX_PROJ}:"
    | sed -e 's/^.*://' -e 's/=.*$//'
    | sort -u
    | sed 's/^/    /'
```

Similarly, `".cdx_projlist"` shows all the possible projects:

```
echo "Possible projects are:"
cat ~/.cdx_data
    | grep ':'
    | sed 's/:.*$//'
    | sort -u
    | sed 's/^/    /'
```

In the meaty scripts, `".cdx_proj"` sets and/or shows the current project:

```
if [[ "$1" != "" ]] ; then
    grep "^$1:" ~/.cdx_data >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then
        echo "No project name '$1'."
        projl
    else
        export CDX_PROJ="$1"
    fi
fi
echo "Current project is: [${CDX_PROJ}]"
```

and `".cdx_goto"` is the same for directories within the project:

```
if [[ "$1" == "." ]] ; then
    CDX_TMP="${CDX_DIR}"
else
    CDX_TMP="$1"
fi
if [[ "${CDX_TMP}" != "" ]] ; then
    grep "^${CDX_PROJ}:${CDX_TMP}=" ~/.cdx_data >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then
            echo "No directory name '${CDX_TMP}' for project '${CDX_PROJ}'."
            cdxl
    else
            export CDX_DIR="${CDX_TMP}"
            cd $(grep "^${CDX_PROJ}:${CDX_DIR}=" ~/.cdx_data
                | sed 's/^.*=//'
                | head -1
                | sed "s:^~:$HOME:")
    fi
fi
CDX_TMP=$(grep "^${CDX_PROJ}:${CDX_DIR}=" ~/.cdx_data
    | sed 's/^.*=//'
    | head -1
    | sed "s:^~:$HOME:")
echo "Current project   is: [${CDX_PROJ}]"
echo "Current directory is: [${CDX_DIR}]"
echo "                      [${CDX_TMP}]"
echo "Actual  directory is: [${PWD}]"
unset CDX_TMP
```

It uses three environment variables which are reserved for its own use: `"CDX_PROJ"`, `"CDX_DIR"` and `"CDX_TMP"`. Other than those and the afore-mentioned files and aliases, there are no other resources used. It's the simplest, yet most adaptable solution I could come up with. Best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

Revisiting. Today I received this link from a social bookmarking site, then I immediately remembered this question:

**[Navigation with bm](http://www.bookmark-tools.com/articles/1.html)**

> We keep a simple, plain text bookmarks
>   file and use a tool called bm to do
>   the look-ups. The tool can also be
>   used to edit the bookmark index
>   dynamically as shown below where we
>   add the directories from the previous
>   example to the index.

Comment: This is a great small command. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

Once i cd'ed into such a long directory, i have that in the history. Then i just type `Ctrl-R` for the "(reverse-i-search)" prompt and type in a few characters, like `Dev/C` that appear somewhere in the path, and it shows me the command what i issued back then and i can easily jump to it again.

That works pretty well in practice. Because it won't find an entry if you haven't typed that path for quite some time, which would mean doing work to make things easier probably wouldn't be worth the time. But it definitely will find it if you used it recently. Which is exactly what i need.

In some way, it's a self-organizing cache for long commands & path-names :)

Comment: Which is unfortunately only useful for absolute paths or for relative cd commands which you happen to have issued from the same location as where you happen to be located at the time you recall the cd command.

Comment: I'm in the habit of always typing "cd" before i go anywhere totally different and often i start with "cd ~/..." (i don't like "../../" style paths). So the path is almost always relative to ~ or correct anyway. It all depends on your habit. The history will adapt to that which is the nice thing

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using a script like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188162/what-is-the-most-useful-script-youve-written-for-everyday-life/245784#245784) in your .bashrc. I've used it on a daily basis ever since I read that post. Pretty bloody useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get some errors. I posted a comment to the url.

Comment: Ah, yes, you might want to replace the 'print' statements with 'echo'. ;-)

Comment: Thank you! 1+ for the awesome tip :)

Answer (score 3):

The user jhs suggested Pushd and Popd-commands. I share here some of my Bash-scripts that I found in Unix Power Tools -book. They are very cool when your directories get a way too long :)

```
#Moving fast between directories 
alias pd=pushd 
alias pd2='pushd +2'  
alias pd3='pushd +3' 
alias pd4='pushd +4'
```

The command 'pushd +n' "rotates" the stack. The reverse command 'popd +n' deletes the n entry of the stack. If your stack gets too long, use 'repeat n popd'. For examle, your stack is 12 directories long:

```
repeat 11 popd
```

When you want to see your stack, write 'pushd'. For further reading, I recommend the book on pages 625-626.

Answer (score 3):

In your .bashrc find

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}[\033[01;32m]\u@\h[\033[00m]:[\033[01;34m]
 \W[\033[00m]\$ '
```

and replace the **\w** with **\W**.I already have it changed here. This will only give you the main directory where you are working. You can get the full directory by typing `pwd`

Comment: I kinda find tmux better for this, instead of finding yourself lost in case directories are have same name:
`set -g automatic-rename-format '#{pane_current_command} #{b:pane_current_path}/'`
Which will show tab like "_<your window format> vim dir/_"

Answer (score 2):

There are fundamental well-known ideas, like creating aliases:

```
alias cdfoo="cd /long/path/to/foo"
```

and also "dropping pebbles"

```
export foo=/long/path/to/foo
```

and also making the above "project-based". I use 'ticket based' directories.

```
 topdir=ticket_12345
 alias cdfoo="cd home/me/sandbox/$topdir/long/path/to/foo"
 export foo="/home/me/sandbox/$topdir/long/path/to/foo"
```

but beyond all this, sometimes it's just handy to jump back and forth to where you've been recently, using command-line menus. (pushd and popd are cumbersome, IMHO).

I use acd_func.sh (listed below). Once defined, you can do

cd --

to see a list of recent directories, with a numerical menu

cd -2

to go to the second-most recent directory.

Very easy to use, very handy.

Here's the code:

```
   # Insert into .profile, .bash_profile or wherever
    # acd_func 1.0.5, 10-nov-2004
    # petar marinov, http:/geocities.com/h2428, this is public domain

    cd_func ()

{
  local x2 the_new_dir adir index
  local -i cnt

  if [[ $1 ==  "--" ]]; then
    dirs -v
    return 0
  fi

  the_new_dir=$1
  [[ -z $1 ]] && the_new_dir=$HOME

  if [[ ${the_new_dir:0:1} == '-' ]]; then
    #
    # Extract dir N from dirs
    index=${the_new_dir:1}
    [[ -z $index ]] && index=1
    adir=$(dirs +$index)
    [[ -z $adir ]] && return 1
    the_new_dir=$adir
  fi

  #
  # '~' has to be substituted by ${HOME}
  [[ ${the_new_dir:0:1} == '~' ]] && the_new_dir="${HOME}${the_new_dir:1}"

  #
  # Now change to the new dir and add to the top of the stack
  pushd "${the_new_dir}" > /dev/null
  [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && return 1
  the_new_dir=$(pwd)

  #
  # Trim down everything beyond 11th entry
  popd -n +11 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null

  #
  # Remove any other occurence of this dir, skipping the top of the stack
  for ((cnt=1; cnt <= 10; cnt++)); do
    x2=$(dirs +${cnt} 2>/dev/null)
    [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && return 0
    [[ ${x2:0:1} == '~' ]] && x2="${HOME}${x2:1}"
    if [[ "${x2}" == "${the_new_dir}" ]]; then
      popd -n +$cnt 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
      cnt=cnt-1
    fi
  done

  return 0
}

alias cd=cd_func

if [[ $BASH_VERSION > "2.05a" ]]; then
  # ctrl+w shows the menu
  bind -x "\"\C-w\":cd_func -- ;"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

This might also be a useful function to put in your `.bashrc`; it moves up either a number of directories, or to a named directory, i.e. if you're in `/a/b/c/d/` you can do `up 3` or `up a` to end up in `a`.

I have no idea where I found this; if you know, please comment or add the attribution.

```
function up()
{
    dir=""
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        dir=..
    elif [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        x=0
        while [ $x -lt ${1:-1} ]; do
            dir=${dir}../
            x=$(($x+1))
        done
    else
        dir=${PWD%/$1/*}/$1
    fi
    cd "$dir";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is right? For some reason, commands, such as "up 3", do not do anything to me. There is even no error message.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to switch to zsh, this is very easy-- just use "alias -g" (global alias, i.e. an alias that works anywhere in the command, not just the first word).

```
# alias -g c=/my/super/long/dir/name
# cd c
# pwd
/my/super/long/dir/name
```

In bash, I think the closest thing you'll get to 'aliasing' style is to write a function:

```
function ccd {
  case "$1" in
    c) cd /blah/blah/blah/long/path/number/one ;;
    foo) cd /blah/blah/totally/different path ;;
    "multiword phrase") cd /tmp ;;
  esac
}
```

This means using something other than "cd" as the command when you want a shortcut, but other than that, it's flexible; you can also add an "ls" to the function so that it always reminds you what's in the directory after you cd, etc.

(Note that to use a multiword argument as above, you need to quote it on the command line, like this:

```
ccd "multiword phrase"
```

so it's not really all that convenient. But it'll work if you need to.)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Andrew Medico's suggestion, check out [J](http://wiki.github.com/rupa/j)

Answer (score 1):

Look into `pushd`, which allows you to maintain a stack of directories which you can push onto, pop off of, or rearrange.

Comment: Very good tip, I am regularly using them. I added some of my Bash-commands as an answer. It looks better in the way.

Comment: You're welcome.  There is no silver bullet for what you are doing, but if you put together several of the very good suggestions you see here, you'll be quite productive!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [autojmp](http://wiki.github.com/joelthelion/autojump/) or [dirmarks](http://ano.malo.us/archives/directory-bookmarks)

Answer (score 1):

Management requires both fast creation and removal of directories. Create many directiories:

```
mkdir -p user/new_dir/new/_dir/.../new_dir
```

Remove recursively many directories (be very careful when you are in lower directories!):

```
rm -r dir/.../new_dir/
```

For further reading, the cheat sheet may help you:

> http://www.scribd.com/doc/2082838/Bash-Command-Line-History-Cheat-Sheet

It contains some nuggets, but I find it rather hard to read. I cannot get commands, like Meta+>, working. They probably help you in navigating long directories.

Answer (score 1):

I realize the question is pretty old, but none of the scripts out there satisfied me, so I wrote a new one.

Here's the requirements I had in mind:

1) Use only bash commands -- I intend to use this on many different unices -- Linux, cygwin, HP-UX, AIX, and a couple others, so I couldn't depend on grep being consistent. Luckily I do have bash everywhere I work.

2) Short code -- I wanted to be able to bind this to a key in GNU screen, and just hit that key to paste the script into the current bash shell I'm using, so that I don't have to setup bash profiles on every system I use.  Anything super long would be annoying and take too much time to paste.

3) No file usage -- Don't want to be littering shared logons with random files.

4) Act just like "cd" in the normal case.  Don't want to have to think about which command to use before I start typing.

5) Provide "up" usage like this answer: [How to manage Long Paths in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670488/how-to-manage-long-paths-in-bash/693290#693290)

6) Keep a list of recently used directories, and switch to the most recent.

Here's the script:

```
#Jump History - Isaiah Damron
function jfind() {
    lp=${JNHIST//==${PWD}==/==}
    lp=${lp%%${lp#==*$1*==}}
    lp=${lp##${lp%==*$1*==*}}
    lp=${lp//==/}
    [[ -d "$lp" ]] && echo $lp && return 0
    return 1;
}
function jadd() {
    [[ -z "$JNHIST" ]] && export JNHIST='=='
    [[ 3000 -lt ${#JNHIST} ]] && export JNHIST=${JNHIST:0:3000} && export JNHIST="${JNHIST%==*}=="
    export JNHIST="==$PWD${JNHIST//==${PWD}==/==}"
}
function j() {
    { cd $* 2> /dev/null && jadd; } \
    || { cd ${PWD/$1*/}$1 2> /dev/null && jadd; } \
    || { jfind $1 \
        && { cd $( jfind $1  ) 2> /dev/null && jadd; } ; } \
    || cd $*
}
function jh() {
    [[ -z "$1" ]] && echo -e ${JNHIST//==/\\n} 
    [[ -n "$1" ]] && jfind $1 && cd $(jfind $1) && jadd
}
```

Usage:

```
jh [parameters]
```

If called on its own, without any parameters, it outputs the current history list.  If it has a parameter, then it searches through the history for the most recently used directory that contains the string $1, and cd's to it.

```
j {parameters}
```

Does `cd parameters`.  If that fails, it checks if any of the parent directories of $PWD match $1, and cd's to it.  If that fails, then it calls `jh $1`.  If that fails, then it outputs the result of `cd parameters`

*Note: I used '==' as an internal separator.  Hopefully you don't have any directories that contain a '==', but if you do you'll have to change around the script.  Just :%s/==/whatever/g*