# Error converting a bash function to a csh alias

Tags: bash, unix, csh, tcsh

I am writing a csh alias so that I can use the following bash function in my csh :

```
function up( )
{
    LIMIT=$1
    P=$PWD
    for ((i=1; i <= LIMIT; i++))
    do
        P=$P/..
    done
    cd $P
    export MPWD=$P
}
```

(I stole the above bash function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188162/what-is-the-most-useful-script-youve-written-for-everyday-life/188560#188560))

I have written this:

```
alias up 'set LIMIT=$1; set P=$PWD; set counter = LIMIT;  while[counter!=0] set counter = counter-1; P=$P/.. ; end cd $P; setenv MPWD=$P'
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
while[counter!=0]: No match.
P=/net/devstorage/home/rghosh/..: Command not found.
end: Too many arguments.
```

and my script is not working as intended. I have been reading up on csh from [here](http://faculty.plattsburgh.edu/jan.plaza/computing/help/tcsh.htm).

I am not an expert in csh and what I have written above is my first csh script. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `csh` uses `setenv` rather than `export`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I changed the export to setenv, but I am still getting teh same error

Comment: @WilliamPursell The question is a lot different now. Can you please look into it (again)?

Comment: In my opinion, the correct solution is: "Don't use csh"!

Comment: arithmetics need the 'at-signment' ("@"); other than that, I agree with William Purlsell. Or, if you really want to use write csh aliases, you'd better read its documentation **very, very carefully**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this

```
alias up 'cd `yes ".." | head -n\!* | tr "\n" "\/"`'
```

`yes ".."` will repeat the string `..` indefinitely; `head` will truncate it to the number passed as argument while calling the alias ( `!*` expands to the arguments passed; similar to `$@` ) and `tr` will convert the newlines to `/`.

radical7's answer seems to be more neat; but will only work for tcsh ( exactly wat you wanted ). This should work irrespective of the shell

Answer (score 1):

You can use the csh's `repeat` function

```
alias up 'cd `pwd``repeat \!^ echo -n /..`'
```

No loops needed (which is handy, because `while` constructs in tcsh seem very finicky)

Answer (score 0):

For multiple lines of code, aliases must be within single quotes, and each end of line must precede a backslash. The end of the last line must precede a single quote to delimit the end of the alias:

```
alias up 'set counter = $1\
set p = $cwd\
while $counter != 0\
@ counter = $counter - 1\
set p = $p/..\
end\
cd $p\
setenv mpwd $p'
```

By the way, variables set with `set` are better with the equal sign separated from the variable name and content; `setenv` doesn't require an equal sign; math functionality is provided by `@`; control structures make use of parentheses (though aren't required for simple tests); use **$cwd** to print the current working directory.

Comment: If experiencing issues with the command editor/history, add `kill -INT $$` to the end of the alias. For numbers, control structures are better used with the greater than (>; >=) and less than (<; <=) operators: `while ( $counter >= 1 )` (This is such a case where parentheses must be used.)