# Is it possible to edit the 'cd' ubuntu command or add functionality with bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cd

So,

`cd ..` moves back into the parent directory.

I'd like to add functionality so that I could type...

`cd ...`

... and move into the parent directory's parent directory.

and consequently move up an additional tier for each extra `.`

The idea came from an [SO answer about a script called 'up'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245724/2673602) which should do essentially the same thing. But I'm curious if it'd be possible to just add to the `cd` command.

After a quick search I've noticed that `cd` is a bash builtin so I don't think it'll be possible to edit any original code. Would it be possible to create a new `cd`(.sh) script that executes in place of the builtin `cd` command when valid arguments are provided? What other ways might this be accomplished by?

Note: this is more for learning than practical application, I just think it'd be a cool thing to do.
Thanks!

Comment: `.` `..` isn't specific to the `cd` command. It is expanded by your shell eg bash. Your shell exands `.` to the current working directory and `..` to the parent of the working directory.

Comment: Using this logic, could I create some kind of interpreter to change `(.. + . * n)` into a valid directory?

Answer (score 3):

You can define an alias in your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias ...='cd ../..'
```

and after that you can issue `...` to go up two directories. If you only want that alias for `cd` it will work.

Comment: simple but effective.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using an alias. I'll definitely consider something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following lines to the file `~/.bashrc`

```
alias cd..='cd ..'
alias cd...='cd ../..'
```

and so on.

After adding this lines close the terminal and open an new one. There you can us `cd..` to go one directory up, `cd...` to go two directories up ...